# How do you properly reference an object variable?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, reference, listobject

This code uses the TestStand input to determine which table to read and write to. After Setting the Worksheet variable to the proper worksheet and the ListObject variable to the proper table, the table data is put into an array for easier reference and passing between Subs.

```
Sub StartTest(TestStand)

Dim TempArray As Variant, PrintTable As ListObject, PrintWrkSht As Worksheet, TRow, TCol

With ThisWorkbook
    If TestStand = 1 Then
        Set PrintWrkSht = .Worksheets("Test Stand 1")
        Set PrintTable = PrintWrkSht.ListObjects("DataRecordTS1")
    End If
    If TestStand = 2 Then
        Set PrintWrkSht = .Worksheets("Test Stand 2")
        Set PrintTable = PrintWrkSht.ListObjects("DataRecordTS2")
    End If
End With

TRow = PrintTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count       
TCol = PrintTable.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 1
    
'Continued
```

Everything goes well until I try to reference PrintTable; it generates this error message:

> "Run-Time error '91: Object variable or with block variable not set"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `TestStand` when you get the error?

Comment: Ah... more likely, maybe `PrintTable` doesn't have a `DataBodyRange`.

Comment: @braX, when the TestStand value is 1, the If statement works.

Comment: So that table does not have a `DataBodyRange`.

Comment: @BigBen, Actually yes, that's correct. It's referencing a table with a header row and an empty body row.

Comment: Normally, this table will be full of data, but initially, it is empty. So I need to add an If statement to account for this, correct?

Comment: That's correct. You can always check `If PrintTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then`.